# Access rights different when using functions/methods in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, function, call

All,

I created a database named Insurance and created a user named iUser with read role to Insurance database and inserted some documents in it.

I connected to Mongo using the user iUser and I was able to fetch the Collections (ExposureFindings) and was able fetch the documents in it as well.

I did the following to accomplish it:

```
C:\> mongo --username iUSer --password xyzpass --authenticationDatabase Insurance

> use Insurance
> db
Insurance
> show collections
ExposureFindings
ExposureProfiles
system.users
>
> db.ExposureFindings.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a83762d560a9792e3b060a4"), "ExposureFindings" : { "_id" : 254090, "CatCode" : "X36", "MainLocInd" : "Y", "ExcludeInd" : "E", "Exposure" : { "CatId" : 237075
2, "CatBasisCode" : "Lloyds823" } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a83762d560a9792e3b060a5"), "ExposureFindings" : { "_id" : 254091, "CatCode" : "A00", "MainLocInd" : "Y", "ExcludeInd" : "S", "Exposure" : { "CatId" : 240471
2, "CatBasisCode" : "Lloyds824" } } }
>
```

Now, If I try the same using the Functions/Methods then it is not returning any documents. Below is what I did.

```
C:\> mongo
> conn = new Mongo()
> InsDB = conn.getDB("Insurance")
> InsDB.auth("iUser","xyzpass")
> InsDB
Insurance
> InsDB.getCollectionNames()
[ "ExposureFindings", "ExposureProfiles","system.users" ]
>  Coll = InsDB.getCollection("ExposureFindings")
Insurance.ExposureFindings
> Coll
Insurance.ExposureFindings
> InsDB.Coll.find()
> -- Returns no rows. However
> Insurance.ExposureFindings.find() -- return the below
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a83762d560a9792e3b060a4"), "ExposureFindings" : { "_id" : 254090, "CatCode" : "X36", "MainLocInd" : "Y", "ExcludeInd" : "E", "Exposure" : { "CatId" : 237075
2, "CatBasisCode" : "Lloyds823" } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a83762d560a9792e3b060a5"), "ExposureFindings" : { "_id" : 254091, "CatCode" : "A00", "MainLocInd" : "Y", "ExcludeInd" : "S", "Exposure" : { "CatId" : 240471
2, "CatBasisCode" : "Lloyds824" } } }
>
```

**Am I doing something wrong while using the InsDB.Coll.find() compared to *db.ExposureFindings.find()* or *InsDB.ExposureFindings.find()*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `Coll` contains the value `Insurance.ExposureFindings`. That is, the `Coll` variable already contains a `<Database>.<Collection>` combination.

```
> Coll
Insurance.ExposureFindings

> InsDB.Coll
Insurance.Coll
```

From the above output, it shows that when you call `InsDB.Coll`, it is looking for the collection named `Coll`. Since the collection `Coll` doesn't exist, it returns nothing.

Proof:

```
> db
Insurance

> db.Coll.insert({_id:0})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> InsDB.Coll.find()
{ "_id" : 0 }
```

To answer your question, let's say the collection contains a single document:

```
> use Insurance
switched to db Insurance

> db.ExposureFindings.find()
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

What you want is either:

```
> InsDB.ExposureFindings.find()
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

or:

```
Coll.find()
{ "_id" : 1 }
```